# SP 2013 CCS Background Image

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, css

I've created a custom HTML and CSS file, uploaded it to SP2013 using design manager, and converted the HTML to a `.masterpage`. I want to set a full page background image, so I've added the following to the `body {`, but the image is not appearing.

If I just add `<img src="dt_images/bg.jpg" />` to the master HTML page, the image appears.

But if I reference the image as such in the CSS, it does not:

```
body { 
    /*background: Gainsboro;*/
    background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Why is this?

---

Edit:

CSS Path:

`background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the image path is correct relative to the CSS file? The CSS looks ok - check the console or fiddler to see if the image is coming through.

Edit: also, try adding `#s4-workspace {background:transparent;}` to make sure you're not getting a V4 background color that's sitting on top of yours.

Comment: Yeah, my file path has been added above. Don't know what's going on.

Comment: Also, the image appears when I run the HTML page locally, but not in SharePoint with the path: `background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint 2013 uses a combination of JavaScript and CSS to set a background on the body. But instead of applying it directly to the HTML `<body>` tag, JavaScript is used to add the CSS class `.ms-backgroundImage` and then apply a `background-image` via CSS.

So, the proper way to set the background image for a JavaScript enabled Web browser is:

```
body.ms-backgroundImage
{
  background: url(../dt_images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```